# how to add any flutter widget inside customscroll view?

Tags: flutter

I want to show a custom message or Text widget when the list is empty inside a custom scroll view . I have sliverapp bar and sliver list in which i am showing the list so when it is empty i want to show it Text but it is giving me errors .

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best for you will be sliver `SliverFillRemaining`.
Do some logic in the slivers of `CustomScrollView`, if the list is empty place the `SliverFillRemaining`, when the list is not empty place the `SliverList`.

Here you have some of the available slivers in Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout#Sliver%20widgets